# Wrong tooltip 'question viewed by' for answer flags in the flag dashboard

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, tooltips, flag-dashboard

The flag dashboard for ♦ moderators contains a (sometimes) helpful list of moderators / staff who visited the flagged post. This information is stored separately for each post; visiting a flagged question does not mark answers as visited, or vice versa.

However, the tooltip for visited answers says "question viewed by" rather than "answer viewed by". For comparison, the flagged question does *not* show my avatar, but rather three of my colleagues (who were hidden to protect the innocent):

[image]

Comment: I'm innocent! :D

Comment: Did you read the question shown after expanding the flagged answer? ;p

Comment: More accurately, I think this reflects which of your fellow mods that Q&A as a whole was viewed by. We don't specifically track views on the question vs. on any specific answer, as far as I know (I don't really know how one would accurately do that).

Comment: @V2Blast from my observations, it's keeping track of whether you visited the link or not. The links to answers have fragments (#) that make sure you end up at the right place on the page. It's different from how (question) views are calculated.